# repeated measures mixed effects using stata - do I use the # or not?

Tags: repeated-measures, stata

I am trying to run a repeated measures mixed effect on some unbalanced panel data that I have using stata.

The data has three hundred observations taken at time 1 and time 2, with 150 distinct person IDs  (SurveyID). Some are measured only once, some are measured twice. I want to know if they responded 1/0 to the outcome variable, based on whether or not they were exposed to the treatment (0/1 at time 1, 0-3 at time 2). I want to control for within-unit correlations by having SurveyID have a random effect, and control for the overall trend due to time using a fixed effect, so that I can better understand the effect of treatment on the outcome.

I cannot figure out if I am suppose to specify it like this:

```
xtmixed outcome treatment#time || SurveyID:
```

or like this:

```
xtmixed outcome treatment time || SurveyID:
```

For non stata users, I guess the question at the core is, for repeated measures mixed effects model, does the fixed effects for time need to be interacted with the treatment (and other variables???), or does including it as a variable control for the impact of time as a fixed effect without interacting it with anything?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to tell us what your variables represent in real life, some context of the data (samle size?) and, what is your goal, what do you want to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have provided more context.

Comment: There is close votes, I think this is more about repeated measures than about stata, so on-topic.